# Value of acceleration vector at maximum speed.

Tags: vectors

**True or False: A moving particle achieves its maximum speed at instant $t = 3$. (Before and after that instant, its speed is less than its speed at $t=3$.) It follows from this that its acceleration is zero at the instant $t =3$.**

I answered true since speed reached its maximum so the derivative must be 0.

The correct answer is false. I can only imagine this has something to do with the acceleration vector's direction. But why? If the acceleration's magnitude is 0 then all the components must be 0 as well. Hence, the acceleration vector must be $<0,0, \cdots, 0>$. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a planet in a perfect circular orbit. It's speed never changes, but it's acceleration is always constant and non-zero (perpendicular to the direction of motion).

In an elliptical orbit the speed is greatest at the closest approach and the acceleration vector is perpendicular to the velocity vector. Here the velocity is changing direction but not magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the derivative of velocity.  Speed is the magnitude of velocity.  Thus, the velocity may change direction, without changing in magnitude, in which case the acceleration is nonzero, while the speed is constant.